# How do you get Xcode8 to respond faster

Tags: xcode8

I just upgraded to Xcode 8 and am effectively stonewalled when trying to do anything. Xcode is taking anywhere from ten seconds to five minutes to execute what i've done. I.e. taking 3 minutes to identify a syntax error, four minutes to run through a for loop in playground of just displaying elements of an array.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, were you able to resolve it? I have tickets opened as a bug report but unsure of how long it will take to hear back.

Comment: My Xcode 8 is working fine. You should post more information, such as detailed version, Mac OS version, output of `ps aux` or `top`, etc.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with Xcode - would suggest your laptop/computer is in need of a clean up. Sure, Xcode can be a little sluggish at times, but you should try Android development - makes Xcode look like a dream.

Comment: Also, open Activity Monitor. Figure out what is actually burning your CPU. Restart Xcode, restart your computer, open a new project.

Comment: Nice to know at least someone has a working version!

I'm running Xcode V 8.2.1 (8C1002) and am running a Mac Pro, El Cap, V 10.11.6.

As for what's displaying in 'top'  CPU is showing 97% idle while editing, then about 87% idle while compiling. Compared with what I had while on Xcode 7 everything is within about 1%.

My program is super small too under 29M.

Comment: I upgraded halfway through a project from 7 to 8 and all the lag happened immediately. Tried a reboot, updated everything (except for my OS) and it's still painfully laggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found someone with a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949491/6484248

which has seemed to have solved my issue as well.

In short, add a User-Defined Setting as:

```
SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION = YES
```

My lag has been completely removed on this project, though I can't explain how it has helped.

Comment: This is the explanation https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/