# Should we stop index file of spotlight for `DerivedData`

Tags: xcode, indexing, deriveddata

`DerivedData` always big and change.

Index this folder looks not help not so much since

1. it's template file.
2. every time indexing kind of slow for every edit & debug circle.
3. Always see it's indexing in Xcode progress bar.

Comment: What is the need? Is there another problem you are experiencing? Are you experiencing performance problems? What mac are you using? What xcode version?

Comment: Xcode build time will always index

Comment: Possible duplication? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547197/xcode-8-0-swift-3-0-slow-indexing-and-building

Comment: @Yeheshuah  It's a little different, I use flutter tool to run also have this problem, so it may related to xcode command line tool or may related to spotlight index.    And that one is using swift, I'm using Objective-C in flutter project.     And my question is should I stop spotlight index for `DerivedData`, wonder any consequence will happened if I do that ?

Comment: As Henry Aloni said: **What is your problem?** Every operating system does a lot housekeeping, but so what, or even better why not? Do you have any problem related to this?

Comment: it's become slow in every debug cycle, since it's indexing every time.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner and it become very high cpu because of this in sometime https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376371/mds-stores-jump-very-high-for-a-while

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is your case due to the lack of information in your question. You can always try deleting the whole `Derived Data` folder - or at least the one corresponding to your application.

If that doesn't help, here are links to two different questions, with their respective answers which I think might be of use.

As stated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784497/4338478):

> Killing the processes named 'swift' and then checking the error in xcode will give you the part of the code giving you trouble. There are some bugs in swift that needs to be circumvented.
>
> To kill the process: Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor. Then find the "swift" process, double click and choose Quit or Force Quit.

I also suggest you try, should the above not work, the recommendations in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834705/4338478)

Comment: It’s not the case, I’d using ObjectC