# XCode 6.1 Very Slow Typing for SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Now I am developing SWIFT Application using XCode 6.1.

Previously I was using XCode 6.0.1 instead, but because of some reasons, I upgrade XCode 6.1.

But unfortunately, I could't type the codes in XCode 6.1 because of slow speed on XCode Code Editor.

It writes the one letter a second.

To be strange, when I work on Objective-C project on same XCode6.1, there is no problem, and all are working well.

But only for swift project, this issue occurs,

When I remove all data from DerivedData folder, this issue disappears but after 1 min, occurs again.

What's wrong? What can I do?

If you have an any idea, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u let XCode for a while for indexing the project. May be this kind of background processes effects your case

Comment: I keep XCode for indexing and after completion, issue occurs again. The problem is that XCode does always indexing while typing every letter.

Comment: How much is your RAM? If low, I suggest you to install more RAMs. I also have experienced Xcode is slow on low RAM macs.

Comment: See this: [Xcode indexing forever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782721/xcode-beta-3-swift-indexing-forever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Xcode 6 make sure you are running Yosemite

- Try re-installing xcode 6.1
- Try restarting your entire system
- Your RAM might be low for some reason, and this could definitely be the cause. Get Memory Clean from the app store to free up some RAM
- Create an entirely new swift project and delete the old one and see if the issue persists

Hopefully one of these options solved your problem!

Comment: I am running XCode6.1 on Mavericks. is it an issue?

Comment: I don't know why I got the downvote because some of this could actually solve the problem. I would think it would run better on Yosemite because I am running it on Yosemite with no problems. Also, when upgrading to Yosemite, Xcode 6 is automatically installed.

Comment: Also, I don't think indexing is the problem because it shouldn't lag up your system like that. I have a 2 year old macbook pro and it does not lag at all at the indexing.