# Xcode 6 building forever

Tags: ios, xcode

OS X Yosemite:10.10.4 , Xcode:6.3.2 and Object-C+Swift.

Today, my project building forever, but I can't find the reason, what caused this situation?

http://7teblm.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/QQ20150624-1@2x.png

Comment: What do you mean?  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I want to know is what reason causes xcode，: (

Comment: There is no point downvoting this question; the issue is obviously one of language and the OP should not be penalized for his lack of English skills.

Comment: @Droppy why does this have anything to do with language. Seems to be in plain English to me the problem I see is that there is a lack of information to actually help this person.

Comment: Well if it was in plain english then we'd be able to understand it.  My issue is the downvoting for not being good at English.

Comment: There is nowhere near the required information to be able to diagnose this issue - that's why it should be downvoted. Size project? Number of resources being added? Number of frameworks being linked? Hardware specification?

Comment: I will only Chinese. : (

Comment: @Droppy as `Jeff` has already said there is nowhere near enough information for us to help. This has nothing to with them not being able to speak/type English well. My downvote is just for the lack of information and nothing else. If you feel that they can't speak/type English enough for you to understand the question then maybe the issue lies with you as I fully understand the question (Including the original before the edit).

Comment: But, the code before you roll back to normal, or so

Comment: @XianweiYin I'm sorry but I don't understand your previous comment. Can you try and make it a bit clearer what you mean? What code do you mean?

Comment: The code before you roll back to normal，project or building forever

Comment: @Bannings this is an English speaking site. Please keep it to English. If you'd like a Chinese speaking version of the site please take a trip over to area51 of stackexchange and support the Chinese speaking version. Other please keep it to English.

Comment: [The solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782721/xcode-swift-indexing-forever)   The last one.